# Ajax email address validator

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Currently the below script works brillantly checking the database using ajax to see if the email address has been used before. My question is how do I stop it checking the database until it is a fully defined `EMAIL` address?

**Form field**

```
<label for="email">Email: *&nbsp;</label><br/>
     <input id="username" name="username" type="email" value="" onblur="return check_username();" />
```

**AJAX script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Loading').hide();    
});

function check_username(){

    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(username.length > 2){
                $.post("../script/check_username_availablity.php", {
            username: $('#username').val(),
        }, function(response){
            $('#Info').fadeOut();

            setTimeout("finishAjax('Info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
        });
        return false;
    }
}

function finishAjax(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
} 

</script>
```

Comment: do a search for `javascript email regex`  or `javascript validate email`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if(username.length > 2){...` use something like:

```
if (/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(username.val())) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/gEL7n/

very similar to what ialencar posted:

```
isValidateEmail = function(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 

check_username = function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(isValidateEmail(username)) {
        $("#username-error").html("");
        console.log("ajax request...");
    } else {
        $("#username-error").html("invalid email address");
    }
}
```